# trace python's call stack address

Tags: python, stack-trace

To track the complete calling history , a.k.a , the sequence of 
'  F_BACK '

Here's my code:

```
import sys
def trace_calls(frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'call':
        return
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    if func_name == 'write':
        return

    caller = frame.f_back

    print ('TRACE\t%s\tF_BACK\t%s' % (caller, frame))
    return

sys.settrace(trace_calls)

def a():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    print("i am A")


def b():
    print("i am B")
    a()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.settrace(trace_calls)
    a()
    b()
```

The output:

```
>TRACE   <frame at 0x7f3c14a80650, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 40, code <module>> F_BACK  <frame at 0x5587b0ee4050, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 21, code a>
>i am A
>TRACE   <frame at 0x7f3c14a80650, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 41, code <module>> F_BACK  <frame at 0x5587b0ec3da0, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 24, code b>
>i am B
>TRACE   <frame at 0x5587b0ec3da0, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 26, code b>        F_BACK  <frame at 0x5587b0ee4050, file '/tmp/test1.py', line 21, code a>
>i am A
```

1. Is my understanding right that  ID is the memory address of the stack frame?
2. if(1.) , why I get same address from 2 calls of function a() ?
3. Through many tests, the ID is more likely to be the entrance of function, that's why it's fixed.
   How I get the address/identifier of frame then?

UPDATE: the first a() call was pushed to the bottom of the stack, because it's the top level call;  the second a() was called inside b(), should be one layer deeper in the stack, but the ID part of the 2 calls is the same.

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have gotten the new frame and its `f_back` mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions do not use the C stack for their data. When you call a function, python creates an execution frame object to hold the local data for that one call. In your example, `a()` creates a frame object on call and that's the frame that holds the first call to `print`. `a` returns, the frame is freed and returned to the heap. The next call `b()` also creates a frame object and it just happens to be the one just freed in the line above. Its print has a new frame that happens to reuse the memory of the previously freed frame.

Comment: I'm very sorry my original code snippet was misleading.  There's an inner call () from inside b(), I fail to format it right the first time. That just makes your answer more confusing.